# Is there any way to disable shutdowning remote machine?

Tags: sudo, root, shutdown, su, init

I sometimes mistakenly shutdown the remote machine by using `sudo init 0`, so I wrote something like in one of my rc files:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
if [ $SSH_CLIENT ]; then
  alias init 'echo Never use init when ssh'
fi
```

However although the rc files is executed, `init` still runs `/sbin/init` rather than the alias. And I don't like to add a global wrapper script into `/usr/local/bin`. Is it possible to disable `sudo init 0` then? Or I have to ask the administrator for help?

Comment: Another approach: put the machine name in the shell prompt. Then you'll be much less likely to forget which machine you're on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `sudo` as a function:

```
sudo() if [ "$1" = init ] && [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
  echo >&2 "Never use init when ssh"
  return 1
else
  command sudo "$@"
fi
```

If you want your aliases expanded after `sudo`, you can still add a

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

it will still call our `sudo` function.

Comment: It works! Some uses such as `sudo ll` will no longer work(where `ll` is an alias defined in my personal rc file; it works when `alias sudo='sudo '`); but it's not important.

Answer (score 3):

For debian and derivatives, there's a piece of software called [`molly-guard`](http://packages.debian.org/sid/molly-guard) that does exactly what you want -- it intercepts a shutdown command if it detects a remote login and asks you to confirm you're sure you're shutting down the right system by entering the name of the system.

Comment: Oh, fantastic! But I think @stephane's advice is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem description I gather you are not using `sudo` very frequently when logged in via SSH. You should just tell that to yourself:

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
  alias sudo='echo "Reconsider your wish, you must!   "'
fi
```

That will make every call to `sudo` result in a warning. If you still want to `sudo init 0` you would have to type `\sudo init 0`. The `\` will make the shell use the real command, not your alias.

However, my actual advice for you is to stop using sudo for the next 5 years. For real.

Comment: as I asked under the question: with regards to not using sudo, why?

Comment: what do you mean you can't take sudoers with you? `/etc/sudoers` can easily be managed and shared among multiple machines, if that's what you mean. and what's better than sudo? it's much better than giving out the root password.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the problem in any way, as presumably @strugee _does_ need privileged access for some things.

Comment: It addresses the problem in that it keeps him from accidently shutting down the remote machine, but offers him an easy way to still do it when he wants. Apparently his own approach was to replace `sudo` with a warning message. And if he has a lot of use for elevated privileges I'd recommend a root shell anyways.

Comment: How will he prevent the same thing in th root shell you recommend? It's a non-solution.

Comment: @mattdm: That warning does work for `sudo init 0` run from a root shell just as well. Running `sudo` from within a root shell would be new to me, but legitimate as `sudo` can do/does more than just elevate rights.